# Efficiently indexing into a 1-dimensional array representing sparse 2-Dimensional Data

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, vector

Given a 2D array sparsely filled with objects containing position and size data (X,Y,W,H) representing objects in 2D space which has been transformed into a 1D array with excess data removed(any empty spaces) is it possible to index into the one dimensional array given a starting point (X,Y) corresponding to a location in the original array using some minimal set of metadata acquired from the original array?

Essentially i'm searching for a way to represent large sets of 2D spatial data without consuming an excess of memory and computing power(a 16,000 by 16,000 array would contain 256,000,000 objects) so getting rid of potentially hundreds of millions of "empty spaces" would represent a large performance gain in both terms of memory usage and cycles wasted looping over empty space.  Computations are being made in real time so keeping data in memory is preferred.

Linked is an example of what i'm trying to accomplish.  Hope it makes sense.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvVZ3.png)

Comment: Have you considered a quad tree or a kd-tree?

Comment: They definitely represent a solution that would work and work well, however i'm 
also curious as to whether or not this can be accomplished with some matrix math magic(allowing us to index directly via some formula vs searching node to node in a tree structure).

Comment: Could you use a `std::unordered_map` using the x,y coordinate as a key? The hash for the coordinate could be `(y << 16) & x`.

Comment: Look into [compressed row storage](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_Row_Storage).

Comment: Will you always know the exact (x,y) coordinate of the cell you want to look up, or do you need to do things like "find the nearest non-empty cell to (x,y)" also?

Comment: Here's an [English-language link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) to the format mentioned above by @nico

Comment: @ChrisD, i've just implemented this.  Appears to be working great, the hash function (y << 16) & x should be a perfect hash assuming that each object contains a different X and Y position correct?

Comment: @Nico & rici This may be exactly what i'm looking for, i'll see if i can implement it with my terrible math skills or find a suitable implementation to do a quick test against std::unordered_map when i get a chance to see how they perform with big data sets.

Comment: @yeet: except that it should be `(y << 16) | x`

Comment: @ybungalobill correct, just noticed all the 0's in the debugger.

Comment: @ybungalobill Correct! Thanks.